# how i open this link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

```js
function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("frm1");

  var text = "";

  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {

    text += x.elements[i].value;

  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.center {

  margin: auto;

  width: 60%;

  border: 3px solid #003fff;

  padding: 10px;

  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<h3>go to city</h3>
<form id="frm1">
  link: <input type="text" name="fname" value=https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/><br><br>
  City: <select name="lname">
       <option value="roma">Rome</option>
       <option value="miami">Miami</option>
       </select><br><br>
</form>
<p>choose your city .</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">open</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

.center {

  margin: auto;

  width: 60%;

  border: 3px solid #003fff;

  padding: 10px;

  text-align: center;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="center">

<h3>go to city</h3>

 

<form id="frm1">

  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value=https://it.wikipedia.org/><br><br>

  City: <select name="lname">

  <option value="Milano">Milano</option>

  <option value="Firenze">Firenze</option>

</select><br><br>

 

</form>

 <p>choose your city .</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">open</button>

<a href id="demo"></a>

</div>
`
<script>

function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("frm1");

  var text = "";

  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {

    text += x.elements[i].value;

  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

}

</script>
`
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the link is inside the text var, how i can open this var?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line in myfunction()

```
window.open(text, "_blank");
```

Sometime this change not work on some browser then use this

```
window.open(text, "_blank").focus();
```